# Cual es el script o librería etc para efectos de destrucción en unity3d

Tags: unity3d

Hola amigos de unity3D disculpa soy programador pero principalmente java y PHP y estoy creando un pequeño juego de dos soldados que se disparan algo sencillo pero necesito que al disparar se vea el efecto de disparo como lo podría hacer eso en unity?

Nota:ya vi su docs pero no la encuentro alguien me podría pasar un link al menos de donde esta

Disculpen soy novato en unity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando dices "libreria o script para efectos" es posible que busques el [**ParticleSystem**](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-ParticleSystem.html).

Lo de destruccion es aparte.

---

Esto en un Script para el player

Ahora **efecto** *que aparece en los codigo*, es un **prefab** de un sistema de particular, por ejemplo podria ser una secuencia de Sprite ect. te dejo por donde mirar:

https://www.youtube.com/results?q=particle+system+unity+prefab

```
// dummy es un gizmo un objeto vacio que poner a la altura del arma por ejemplo dentro del arbol del personaje (lo puedes añadir arrastrandolo en el edito dentro del objeto personaje por ejemplo).

public Transform dummy; 
public GameObject efecto;

//donde quieras que se active la explosion por ejemplo al pulsar x tecla añades algo asi

//..
//if.. key active

    Instantiate(efecto, dummy.position, dummy.rotation);
```

Esto en el objeto que es disparado o lo que sea, es un simulacion para destruccion o cuando el disparo impacta sobre el, en este caso usamos un enemigo como ejemplo.

```
public GameObject efecto;

//donde quieras que se active la explosion en este caso usamo un collider se tiene que agregar previamente de no tenerlo 

//..
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other){

  if(other.gameObject.tag == "Enemigo"){

      Instantiate(efecto, transform.position, transform.rotation);
      Destroy(other.gameobject);
  }
}
```

**[Instantiate](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html)** Esta función hace una copia de un objeto de una manera similar al comando Duplicar en el editor.

---

En esta [pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/49121/unity-como-delimitar-dos-%C3%A1reas-para-encontrar-y-borrar-objetos/49128#49128) se trata sobre **Collider** y se mencionan el uso de los **Tag** ect por si tienes alguna duda quizas te ayude.

---

Lo de arriba es para crear explosiones ect.

Creo que es a lo que te refieres cuando dices efecto disparo, de echo el segundo codigo es para usarlo en algo que se mueva por ejemplo un bala, que al entrar en contato con el enemigo activa una explosion.

Tomese el codigo como pseudocode, o como una idea.

*Por otro lado te recomiendo que veas alguno de los mucho videos sobe unity en youtube sobre algun juego sencillo o en el canal official de Unity existen bastantes videos que te pueden ser utiles en un futuro.*